# How to populate JTextFields in new window from JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I created window with JTable that contains values from text file about some users.
Also, there is buttons for Create, Edit and Delete users.
I want to use and open the same Window for Create and Edit button, but if Edit button is clicked then window should be populated with values of higlighted (clicked) user from JTable.

```
//PatientWindow.java

private void initActions() {

        btnCreate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                CreateEditPatientWindow createEditPatientWindow = new CreateEditPatientWindow();
                createEditPatientWindow.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        btnUpdate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int row = tblPatients.getSelectedRow();
                if(row == -1)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must select row for update", "Info", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                }
                else 
                {
                    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)tblPatients.getModel();
                    String username = model.getValueAt(row, 6).toString();
                    UserModel userSearch = UsersClass.findUser(username);                   


                    if(userSearch != null)
                    {
                        //System.out.println("USER FOUND!!!" + username);   
                        //PatientModel patientModel = patient;
                        //patientModel.setUsername(username);

                        CreateEditPatientWindow createEditPatientWindow = new CreateEditPatientWindow(USE VALUES OF SELECTED USER);
                        createEditPatientWindow.setVisible(true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User not found", "Info", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
private void initGUI() {

        tbToolBar = new JToolBar();

        btnCreate = new JButton("Create");
        btnUpdate = new JButton("Update");
        btnDelete = new JButton("Delete");

        tbToolBar.add(btnCreate);
        tbToolBar.add(btnUpdate);
        tbToolBar.add(btnDelete);

        spScroll = new JScrollPane();

        ArrayList<PatientModel> patientsList = UsersClass.getPatients();
        String[] header = new String[] {
                "Name", 
                "Lastname", 
                "UMCN", 
                "Gender", 
                "Adress", 
                "Phone number", 
                "Username",
                "Password",
                //"User type",
                "Insurance number",
                "Insurance category",
                "Expiry date"};
        Object[][] body = new Object[patientsList.size()][header.length];
        int a = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < patientsList.size(); i++) 
        {
            PatientModel patientsData = patientsList.get(i);
            body[i][0] = patientsData.getName();
            body[i][1] = patientsData.getLastname();
            body[i][2] = patientsData.getUmcn();
            body[i][3] = patientsData.getGender();
            body[i][4] = patientsData.getAdress();
            body[i][5] = patientsData.getPhoneNumber();
            body[i][6] = patientsData.getUsername();
            body[i][7] = patientsData.getPassword();
            //body[i][8] = patientsData.getUserType();
            body[i][8] = patientsData.getHealthInsuranceNumber();
            body[i][9] = patientsData.getInsuranceCategory();
            body[i][10] = patientsData.getExpiryDate();
        }

        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(body,header);
        tblPatients = new JTable(tableModel);
        //tblPatients.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
        //tblPatients.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
        //tblPatients.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        tblPatients.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, null);

        JScrollPane tableScroll = new JScrollPane(tblPatients);
        add(spScroll);
        add(tbToolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(tableScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }



//CreateEditPatientWindow.java

private void initGUI() {
        MigLayout mig = new MigLayout("wrap 2", "[][]", "[]10[][]10[]");
        setLayout(mig);     

        lblName = new JLabel("Name");
        txtName = new JTextField(20);       

        lblLastname = new JLabel("Lastname");
        txtLastname = new JTextField(20);

        lblUMCN = new JLabel("Unique Master Citizen Number");
        txtUMCN = new JTextField(20);

        lblGender = new JLabel("Gender");
        cbGender = new JComboBox();
        cbGender.addItem("Male");
        cbGender.addItem("Female");

        lblAdress = new JLabel("Adress");
        txtAdress = new JTextField(20);

        lblPhoneNumber = new JLabel("Phone number");
        txtPhoneNumber = new JTextField(20);

        lblUsername = new JLabel("Username");
        txtUsername = new JTextField(20);

        lblPassword = new JLabel("Password");
        txtPassword = new JTextField(20);

        lblHealthInsuranceNumber = new JLabel("Health insurance number");
        txtHealthInsuranceNumber = new JTextField(20);

        lblExpiryDate = new JLabel("Expiry date");
        txtExpiryDate = new JTextField(20);

        lblInsuranceCategory = new JLabel("Insurance category");
        cbInsuranceCategory = new JComboBox();
        cbInsuranceCategory.addItem("1");
        cbInsuranceCategory.addItem("2");
        cbInsuranceCategory.addItem("3");



        btnConfirm = new JButton("Confirm");

        add(lblName);
        add(txtName);

        add(lblLastname);
        add(txtLastname);

        add(lblUMCN);
        add(txtUMCN);

        add(lblGender);
        add(cbGender);

        add(lblAdress);
        add(txtAdress);

        add(lblPhoneNumber);
        add(txtPhoneNumber);

        add(lblUsername);
        add(txtUsername);

        add(lblPassword);
        add(txtPassword);

        add(lblHealthInsuranceNumber);
        add(txtHealthInsuranceNumber);

        add(lblExpiryDate);
        add(txtExpiryDate);

        add(lblInsuranceCategory);
        add(cbInsuranceCategory);

        add(btnConfirm);    
    }
```

Also here is UsersClass that contains methods for populateing Arrays with every type of users (patients, nursers, doctors) etc..

```
public class UsersClass {

    public static ArrayList<UserModel> users = getUsers();
    public static ArrayList<PatientModel> patients = getPatients();


    public static ArrayList<UserModel> getUsers()
    {
        ArrayList<UserModel> usersList = new ArrayList<UserModel>();
        ArrayList<PatientModel> patientsList = getPatients();
        ArrayList<NurseModel> nursesList = getNurses();
        ArrayList<DoctorModel> doctorsList = getDoctors();

        usersList.addAll(patientsList);
        usersList.addAll(nursesList);
        usersList.addAll(doctorsList);

        return usersList;
    }


    public static ArrayList<PatientModel> getPatients()
    {
        ArrayList<PatientModel> patientsList = new ArrayList<PatientModel>();
        try
        {
            File patientTextFile = new File("src/txt/patients");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(patientTextFile));
            String line = null;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String[] split = line.split("\\|");
                String name = split[0];
                String lastname = split[1];
                String umcn = split[2];
                String gender = split[3];
                String adress = split[4];
                String phoneNumber = split[5];
                String username = split[6];
                String password = split[7];
                String userType = split[8];
                int healthInsuranceNumber = Integer.parseInt(split[9]);
                String expiryDate = split[10];
                int insuranceCategory = Integer.parseInt(split[11]);

                PatientModel newPatient = new PatientModel(
                        name, 
                        lastname, 
                        umcn, 
                        gender, 
                        adress, 
                        phoneNumber,
                        username,
                        password,
                        userType,
                        healthInsuranceNumber,
                        expiryDate,
                        insuranceCategory);
                patientsList.add(newPatient);               
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return patientsList;
    }


    public static ArrayList<NurseModel> getNurses()
    {
        ArrayList<NurseModel> nursesList = new ArrayList<NurseModel>();
        try
        {
            File nurseTextFile = new File("src/txt/nurses");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nurseTextFile));
            String line = null;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String[] split = line.split("\\|");
                String name = split[0];
                String lastname = split[1];
                String umcn = split[2];
                String gender = split[3];
                String adress = split[4];
                String phoneNumber = split[5];
                String username = split[6];
                String password = split[7];
                String userType = split[8];
                double salary = Double.parseDouble(split[9]);
                String service = split[10];
                NurseModel newNurse = new NurseModel(
                        name, 
                        lastname, 
                        umcn, 
                        gender, 
                        adress, 
                        phoneNumber,
                        username,
                        password,
                        userType,
                        salary,
                        service);
                nursesList.add(newNurse);               
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return nursesList;
    }


    public static ArrayList<DoctorModel> getDoctors()
    {
        ArrayList<DoctorModel> doctorsList = new ArrayList<DoctorModel>();
        try
        {
            File doctorTextFile = new File("src/txt/doctors");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(doctorTextFile));
            String line = null;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String[] split = line.split("\\|");
                String name = split[0];
                String lastname = split[1];
                String umcn = split[2];
                String gender = split[3];
                String adress = split[4];
                String phoneNumber = split[5];
                String username = split[6];
                String password = split[7];
                String userType = split[8];
                double salary = Double.parseDouble(split[9]);
                String specialization = split[10];
                String service = split[11];
                DoctorModel newDoctor = new DoctorModel(
                        name, 
                        lastname, 
                        umcn, 
                        gender, 
                        adress, 
                        phoneNumber,
                        username,
                        password,
                        userType,
                        salary,
                        specialization,
                        service);
                doctorsList.add(newDoctor);             
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return doctorsList;
    }   


    public static UserModel findUser(String username)
    {
        for(UserModel user : users)
        {
            if(user.getUsername().equals(username))
            {
                return user;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you:

1. Create a custom TableModel for your "User" objects. See [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for a step by step example on how to do this.
2. Then when you create your popup dialog you pass in a "User" object to the dialog. If the "New" button is clicked, you pass in an empty "User" object. If the "Edit" button is clicked you get the "User" object from the custom TableModel
3. The code in your dialog class with then simply display the data from the "User" object.
4. Then when the dialog is closed you need to update the "User" object with the data entered in the text filed of the dialog. If "Edit" was clicked you just repaint() the table to see the new data. If "New" was clicked, you then add the User Object to the TableModel.

Comment: Step 2 is exactly what I asked how to do it.
I edited my question and aded code for table model and UserModel.
So could you help me with some code sample tip on this specifically example?